# How to confirm when more than one AJAX call has completed?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list1").jqGrid({
        url: 'example1.php',
        /*balabala...*/
        gridComplete: function() {

        }
    });

    $("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: 'example2.php',
        /*balabala...*/
        gridComplete: function() {

        }
    });

    /*I want to do something here, but the above grids must be both complete first.*/
    Something...
});
```

How should I do ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to put your "something" in the `gridComplete` callbacks but have the two callbacks check that the other one has finished. Something along these lines:

```
function do_something_wonderful() {
    // This is the awesome stuff that you want to
    // execute when both lists have loaded and finished.
    // ...
}

var one_done = false;
function done_checker() {
    if(one_done) {
        // The other one is done so we can get on with it.
        do_something_wonderful();
    }
    one_done = true;
}

$("#list1").jqGrid({
    //blah blah blah
    gridComplete: done_checker
});
$("#list2").jqGrid({
    //blah blah blah
    gridComplete: done_checker
});
```

This nicely extends to more than two lists with a couple small modifications:

- use `var how_many_done = 0;` instead of `one_done`.
- Do a `++how_many_done;` instead of `one_done = true;` and move it to the top of `done_checker`.
- Replace the `if(one_done)` with `if(how_many_done == number_of_tasks)` where `number_of_tasks` is how many AJAX tasks you have.

The general version would look sort of like this:

```
var number_of_tasks = 11; // Or how many you really have.
var how_many_done   = 0;
function done_checker() {
    ++how_many_done;
    if(how_many_done == number_of_tasks) {
        // All the AJAX tasks have finished so we can get on with it.
        do_something_wonderful();
    }
}
```

An even better version would wrap up the state in a closure:

```
var done_checker = (function(number_of_tasks, run_when_all_done) {
    var how_many_done = 0;
    return function() {
        ++how_many_done;
        if(how_many_done == number_of_tasks) {
            // All the AJAX tasks have finished so we can get on with it.
            run_when_all_done();
        }
    }
})(do_something_wonderful, 11);
```

Comment: @Cynial: I added another update that isolates the extra state, it might be a bit much though.

Comment: Don't talk in that way, It really help me! :)

Comment: @Cynial: I just added another option that might be helpful or it might be more protection/cleverness than you need (i.e. "a bit much"). Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be currently using the [jquery deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).