# Browser crashes after 10-15 mins

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, dygraphs

In my app I'm displaying 10 charts (charts are from [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/).) to monitor data. For displaying charts I'm getting data from my sever by sending ajax request to 4 servlets on every 5 seconds. After 10-15 mins (don't know exact time.) my browser crashes saying "aw!! snap." What could be the reason? Is it javascript that is causing it? or is it because I'm sending request every 5 seconds?

Browser tested: Firefox and Chorme.

Note:- When I refresh the browser after crash it again works fine for 10-15 mins.

---

JS code:

```
var i=0;
var loc = new String();
var conn = new String();
var heapUsage = new String();
var cpuUsage = new String();
var thrdCnt = new String();
var heapUsageConsole = new String();
var cpuUsageConsole = new String();
var thrdCntConsole = new String();
var user = new String();
var MemTotal = new String();
function jubking(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "MonitorDBServlet";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var strArr = str.split(",");
    url = "MonitorTomcatServlet";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var appstr = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var appArr = appstr.split(",");
    url = "MonitorConsoleTomcatServlet";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var appstrConsole = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var appArrConsole = appstrConsole.split(",");
    url = "CpuMemoryServlet";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var statesStr = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var states = statesStr.split(",");
    if(i>30){
        loc = loc.substring(loc.indexOf("\n")+1);
        loc += i+","+strArr[0]+","+strArr[1]+"\n";
            //--- Do same thing all other var
} else {
        loc += i+","+strArr[0]+","+strArr[1]+"\n";
            //--- Do same thing all other var
    }
    document.getElementById("dbSize").innerHTML = strArr[3];
    document.getElementById("HeapMemoryUsageMax").innerHTML = appArr[1];
    document.getElementById("HeapMemoryUsageMaxConsole").innerHTML = appArrConsole[1];
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dbLocks"),
        ",locksheld,lockswait\n"+loc+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("activeConnection"),
                    ",Connections\n"+conn+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example2"),
                       ",heapUsage\n"+heapUsage+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example3"),
                       ",cpuUsage\n"+cpuUsage+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example4"),
                       ",thread,peakThread\n"+thrdCnt+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example6"),
                       ",heapUsage\n"+heapUsageConsole+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example7"),
                       ",\n"+cpuUsageConsole+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("example8"),
                       ",thread,peakThread\n"+thrdCntConsole+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("cpuStates"),
                       ",user,system,nice,idle\n"+user+"");
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("memStates"),
                     ",MT,MF,B,C,ST,SF\n"+MemTotal+"");
    i = i + 1;
    setTimeout("jubking()", 5000);
}
```

Comment: Does it run out of memory (i.e. store the data continiously)?

Comment: No the data is only displayed I'm not storing data in database. But yes I'm storing previous 20 response values in comma separated string in js.

Comment: And you are sure its not being cached anywhere (just check the memory load i guess)

Comment: @soandos: how can I check that? Does firebug shows that?

Comment: Check the memory use of the browser process using task manager or similar - it could be an out-of-memory thing, especially if you are storing potentially large datasets.

Comment: @harry joy: I would just use task manager, but there might be a way to use firebug, not sure

Comment: @mu is too short: it takes round 2-3 secs to complete all requests in servlet.

Comment: @Kargen, @soandos,@mu is too short: Last time ff crashes the amount of memory in task manager was: 1,923,481 K. is it too much memory for browser. No other tabs were open.

Comment: @mu is too short: I have added my js code in question. Can you help me in finding memory issues?

Comment: @mu is too short: I tried calling `delete` in js to remove variables but still facing browser crashes.

Comment: @mu is too short:- Actually what I found is that memory leak is because of charts because when I remove all the graphs creating script that is `g = new DyGraph(....` browser never crashes. So now I'm trying to find some line graph script that will not face this issue. Do you any good js script to draw a line graph that can look like jConsole's graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `dygraphs` usage is, as you note in your comments, the source of your trouble. It looks like you're binding new graphs over and over again when you only want to update the data, using a moving window for the data would also help. Try reworking your updater to work like this pseudo-JavaScript:

```
var graphs = {
    dbLocks: {
       graph: new DyGraph(/* ... */),
       data:  [ ]
    },
    activeConnection: {
        graph: new DyGraph(/* ... */),
        data:  [ ]
    },
    // etc.
};

var DATA_WINDOW_SIZE = 1000; // Or whatever works for you.

function update(which, new_data) {
    var g = graphs[which];
    g.data.push(new_data);
    if(g.data.length > DATA_WINDOW_SIZE)
        g.data.shift();
    g.graph.updateOptions({ file: g.data });
}

function jubking() {
    // Launch all your AJAX calls and bind a callback to each
    // one. The success callback would call the update() function
    // above to update the graph and manage the data window.

    // Wait for all the above asynchronous AJAX calls to finish and
    // then restart the timer for the next round.
    setTimeout(jubking, 5000);
}
```

The basic idea is to use window on your data with a reasonable maximum width so that the data doesn't grow to chew up all your memory. As you add a new data point at the end of your data cache, you drop old ones off the other end once you hit your maximum comfortable size.

You can find some techniques for waiting for several asynchronous AJAX calls to finish over here: [How to confirm when more than one AJAX call has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932432/how-to-confirm-when-more-than-one-ajax-call-has-completed/5932560#5932560) (disclosure: yes, that's one of my other answers).

Comment: what is the use of `data:[]`? how to use it?

Comment: @Harry: That's just the current data that you're displaying, you need to keep track of that in order to limit how much data the DyGraphs are trying to display (hence the `.shift()` to drop off the first element when you get too many). I'm guessing that DyGraph keeps growing in size as you add more and more data to it so I'm trying to limit how much data DyGraph has to handle.

Comment: @mu is too short: currently I'm saving values in `loc` so does `data` is same as `loc`? can I replace it by `loc`?

Comment: @Harry: You can track the data however you want (as long as you limit the size of the data array), the code I included was just to illustrate the technique I had in mind.

Comment: @mu is too short: I'm asking because I have to pass data in DyGraphs constructor and you have taken it as a separate.

Comment: @Harry: Right but my reading of the documentation indicates that you can update the data set using `updateOptions`. So you create a DyGraph with an empty data set and then update the data on the existing DyGraph. I think your original code might have been creating a bunch of DyGraphs on top of each other and that might have been part of your problem.

Comment: @mu is too short: this is not working. I'm not getting any charts.

Comment: @mu is too short: this line is not executing: `var g = graphs[which];`  what could be the reason? I'm passing the name correct: `update('dbLocks', loc);`

Comment: @Harry: What does your debugger say? The pseudo code in my answer was meant to illustrate the idea, it is not meant to be a functional piece of software.

Comment: @mu is too short: debugger doesn't shows anything when it comes to line and I press go to next step and the debugging gets stop and nothing is displayed on screen.

Comment: @mu is too short: okay the problem is my graphs variable remains undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`about:crashes`](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Mozilla%20Crash%20Reporter#w_viewing-crash-reports) in FF to view the specific reason for your crash. As mentioned by others, you could be leaking memory if you're caching off data (assigning it to a variable) returned by your AJAX call and not clearing it when the next call is made.

**Edit:**

Just saw your comment - 1,923,481 K is *definitely* too much - you're leaking data somewhere. What OS are you running? If you run FF from console in *nix, you usually get some form of a dump into console when something's going wrong (not sure about Windows).

You could possibly try decreasing your poll intervals to once every few seconds and step through the script using Firebug or Chrome's debugger to see what's happening. Worst case, start commenting things out until you figure out *exactly* what is making your app crash. And then, figure out a way to fix it :)

Comment: I have done as said on link. But when click on crash report link it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: I have added my js code in question. Can you help me in finding memory issues?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above advocates re-using your Dygraph object and calling `g.updateOptions({file:...})` to reduce memory usage. This is a great way to do it.

The other way is to call `g.destroy()` before you redefine the Dygraph object. This will make dygraphs clear out all of its internal arrays and DOM references. Example:

```js
g = new Dygraph(...);
g.destroy();
g = new Dygraph(...);
```

Read more here: http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/01/preventing-dygraphs-memory-leaks.html