# Will this JavaScript script result in a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

This question depends my previous question: [Browser crashes after 10-15 mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973993/browser-crashes-after-10-15-mins) On that question I got answer saying my code is doing memory leak. So I'm trying to find the point where memory leak is going on.

Will this script will result in memory leak?

```
var j = function (i, q, r, a) {
        return function (s) {
            var p = r.annotation;
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                p[i](p, r, a.dygraph_, s)
            } else {
                if (a.dygraph_.attr_(q)) {
                    a.dygraph_.attr_(q)(p, r, a.dygraph_, s)
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

If yes then is there any solution that I can do to prevent memory leak?

Comment: This doesn't look like anything that should produce browser crashes unless it loops itself somewhere.

Comment: @Cobra_Fats : every time I call `g=new Dygraph(..` this will be called.

Comment: It's possible to leak memory in JavaScript?

Comment: @ultimatebuster: yes it is possible and because of that your browser will crash in some time.

Comment: Would calling `document.write` 5 million times cause this? I thought most modern browser has preventions of those, by terminating unresponsive scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not apparent if there are memory leaks, but if this were my code, I would change it like so (not counting the bad variable naming):

```
var j = function (i, q, r, a) {
    var p = r.annotation,
        dygraph = a.dygraph_;

    return function (s) {
        if (p.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            p[i](p, r, dygraph, s);
        } else {
            var aqExpression = dygraph.attr_(q);

            if (aqExpression) {
                aqExpression(p, r, dygraph, s);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're leaking memory with that code.

Leaking memory usually happens when DOM elements are involved.

I wrote this guide to memory leak patterns in JavaScript and how to debug them: http://www.vladalexandruionescu.com/2012/08/javascript-memory-leaks.html. Hope you'll find it useful.